# Transnormal function and isoparametric function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let M be a connected complete Riemannian manifold and denote by $\nabla$ and $\triangle$ the Levi-Civita connection and the Laplace operator of M, respectively. A non-constant function f of class $C^{2}$ on $M$ is called transnormal if
\begin{equation}\label{RK 1}
 |\nabla f|^{2}=b(f)
\end{equation}
for some real function b of class $C^{2}$ defined on the range of $f$, and  $f$ is called isoparametric if, in addition to the first equation, it satisfies
\begin{equation}\label{RK 2}
  \triangle(f) = a(f)
\end{equation}
for some continuous real function a defined on the range of $f$. The first equation implies that the level sets of $f$ are parallel to each other. The second equation implies that a level hypersurface has constant mean curvature.
Qustion: If $f$ is transnormal function and  the level sets of $f$ are parallel to each other, how to prove that $f$ is isoparametric function?

Comment: It displays nicer if you use `\Delta` instead of `\triangle` for the Laplacian operator.

Answer (score 1):

For spaces of constant curvature this has been done by Élie Cartan in [Familles de surfaces isoparamétriques dans les espaces à courbure constante](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02410700?LI=true).

In general, however, your claim is not true. See Theorem 1.4 in [Transnormal functions on Riemannian manifolds](https://www.math.tohoku.ac.jp/people/miyaoka/Transnormal-Miyaoka.pdf) by Reiko Miyaoka.